# Use keyboard shortcut automatically in nano?

Tags: nano

I'd like the line numbers to show automatically whenever I use nano. I've seen the `set const` command in `~/.nanorc` but I want to see the line numbers in the column to the left, activated by `meta-#` within nano. Is there a way to automatically use `meta-#` whenever I use `nano` without having to do it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the latest version but browsing through the sources [online](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/log/?qt=grep&q=M-%23) shows that `M-#` is setting an option called *linenumbers*, and indeed this is described in the new man page for [nanorc](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.8/nanorc.5.html):

> `set linenumbers`
>
>   Display line numbers to the left of the text area.

There is also a command line `-l` or `--linenumbers` option.